# NSMutableArray not being populated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

The code for my `UITableView` is not being red, which can only meen my array is not being populated. 
I am using a `core-database` and as I can see from the print i get it shows that my DB has the data in it. It is just not being displayed.
Here is my code:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:nil];

    [self reloadArray];

}
-(void) reloadArray
{

    AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];
    NSManagedObject *object = nil;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    for (int i = 0; i <  [result count]; i ++) {
        object = [result objectAtIndex:i];
        [_projectArray addObject:[object valueForKey:@"name"]];
    }



}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [self reloadArray];
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [_projectArray count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellID = @"TableCell";
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.projectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    cell.textLabel.text = [_projectArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    return cell; 
}
```

Comment: First of all set a breakpoint after executing a fetch request and check what error variable says.

Comment: Why do you need [self reloadArray]; in numberOfSectionsInTableView?

Comment: When setting the breakpoint , It shows that Error = nil, and it shows there are 4 rows in the tableview, 4 items in the Entity @"Project" and 4 items in the array.

Comment: it loads reloads  all the info when the tableview is being load, its just an extra load i added when it did not display

Comment: so, is problem already solved?

Comment: No still not displaying.

Comment: Is method tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: called at all?

Comment: Do you initialise _projectArray at all or is it nil?

Answer (score 2):

You're setting your `delegate` and `dataSource` in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. These need to be set when setting up the table view initially, **not** when a `delegate` method is being called (because that method will never get called).

To re-iterate, set your `delegate` and `dataSource` properties in `viewWillAppear:animated:` or `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

Failing to set these before calling `reloadData` will result in none of your `delegate` or `dataSource` methods being called.